# What is offset in <li> tag in Edge browser, which is not coming chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

In Edge browser, my li tags has lot of space in between. When checking the computed property CSS tab, it showing `offset` in box model. Which is not coming in chrome and rendered perfectly. The difference and computed property can be seen in the pic attached (Edge first and then Chrome).

Source: https://codepen.io/hemkaran/pen/VJmjOy

Demo Link: https://s.codepen.io/hemkaran/debug/VJmjOy/yPAJjXVKDVgA

[image: IE browser]

[image: Chrome Browser]

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264767/internet-explorer-box-model-what-is-offset

Comment: Please try to post your HTML and CSS code. It can help us to check the code and test the issue with multiple browsers. With only image we cannot get the proper idea  about the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Sorry, I can't comment that just wanted to have general insight if anybody already knows about that.

Comment: we do not have any information regarding this. We made a test with simple sample but issue is not producible with MS Edge. So it is better if you post any code that can produce the issue. It can help us to understand the issue in better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Sorry for the late reply. Edited the question, added codepen link. If you open demo link in IE11, it will have a lot of space above.

Answer (score 1):

I again try to test the issue and I find that issue is producible with your sample code.

Based on my testing results, it looks like MS Edge has some issue with **display:flex**.

When I try to unchecked it than it removes that extra space.

[image]

I had also tested the issue with [new chromium Edge](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download) and it worked fine.

At present, you can try to apply alternative style for **display:flex** may help to avoid this issue in MS Edge.

I will try to provide feedback to Microsoft engineers regarding this issue.

Thanks for your understanding.