# IE showing gap between two div but not in chrome

Tags: css, html

We have simple div as below. The problem here there is gap between the div gpsDataDiv and map div inIE. Secondly the gpsDataDiv is field with a dynamic table using this method document.getElementById("gpsDataDiv").innerHTML = htmlString; and again in IE the table goes right below and does not stop at say 400px so there is no scroll bar generated like in chrome or firefox.

```
 <body>
 <div id="left" style="width:220px;height:350px;float:left;background:white;">
      <div id="gpsDataDiv" style="overflow: auto; max-height: 400px;background:white;"></div>
</div>
 <div id="map" style="top:0px;left:220px;height:100%">Map goes here.
  </div>    
 </body>
```

Comment: Are you using a proper DOCTYPE, so that the document is in Standards mode? Also you'll probably need to show the complete relevant styles. Best would be a working example online such as an jsfiddle.

Comment: Did either my or Guiseppe's answer help you sort out your issue? If so can you please mark as accepted.

Comment: @ROTORa what is the importance of the DOCTYPE?

Comment: @user837306 Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You div with id `map` does not have `position:absolute` in the styling, is this something you have in a separate stylesheet?

A couple of suggestions:

**1.**

Your mixing `float:left;` with an absolutely positioned element(?). You need to make sure that the container, in this case the body has either `overflow:hidden` applied to it, or alternatively use a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html). This will stop the container from collapsing down and can cause problems further down your page.

**2.**

Secondly, you should be able to alter the style in different browsers by using either separate stylesheets aimed towards each browser ([try a search for ie specific stylesheets](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)) or try my approach of using a class on the html element

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

**3.**

Make sure you have a doctype on your page, try using the html 5 doctype below. If you don't specify a doctype the page can go into quirks mode. This is definitely something you don't want!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**4.**

Try changing `max-height: 400px;` to `height: 400px` on `id="gpsDataDiv"`

---

If any of these arent helping you, could you put together a jsfiddle of your issue? Itll help me debug it for you :)

Comment: for your 1 suggestion I have done this now put the position absolute and remove the float:left but I am not too sure where to add overflow:hidden. I have put the suggestion 3. and 4. too. It looks much better the space is gone in IE but one problem from the top there is a bit of space before the table start <div id="left" style="width:220px;height:350px;background:white;">
    <div id="gpsDataDiv" style="overflow: auto; height: 400px;background:white;"></div>
</div>
 <div id="map" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:220px;width:100%;height:100%">Map goes here.
  </div>

Comment: additionally my table scroll bar looks like slightly covered by the map div. In addition I want to master how to work with the float,position and overflow. Where is the right place I could start to master this?

Comment: @user837306 You could try this guide -> http://www.smashingmagazine.com/mastering-css-principles-comprehensive-reference-guide/#n1

Comment: how about the little space at the top between the top and the table?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem. It seems to show correctly in IE if I add height: 400px to gpsDataDiv.

Comment: how about the space do you get it ?

Comment: Maybe you are in IE quirks mode, getting some unwanted offset. See this answer for reference: 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817745/how-do-i-get-rid-of-an-elements-offset-using-css)

Comment: ok I will look into it but now I got another problem the table has a little space between the top that is even in chrome too.