# Extra Space in IE table

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html-table, whitespace

**Issue #1 -** 
I have read all about different solutions for getting rid of the "white space" in IE within tables, but nothing has worked so far! The page I am working on displays OK in Firefox and all other browsers. I have tried the height=100% command but that makes things so much worse and spaced out, and I have also tried deleting spaces between the different table and td tags but that doesn't change anything either. The images are exactly 115px square or twice that for a horizontal or vertical image.

**Issue #2 -** 
I have an image gallery for each image that is SUPPOSED to appear when clicking on the image. It appears fine in Firefox and Chrome, but IE won't show the image gallery. Help on getting that javascript to work?

You can see our "live" site at [www.tracystonearchitect.com](http://www.tracystonearchitect.com) (it is just the main home page - the rest of the site is in flash.. which we are working on converting) - it appears 100% correct in Chrome, the spacing issue and image gallery issue shows up in IE, and in Firefox the fonts I used aren't loading right.. which is another issue that I may have already figured out locally, but havent posted the updates yet.

I'm still pretty new at all this coding stuff, so may be a user-error. I've also been trying different techniques to fix these problems so things may be a bit awry based on my trying the different solutions. I'd appreciated any ideas or thoughts on how to fix the space-- or any other code technique comments!

Please help, I really need a solution for this.

Comment: I think you'll get more help if you split these up into two questions. One's focused on HTML/CSS and the other's javascript.

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing?

Comment: i've been testing mostly in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

As Per Issue #1

Do you have developer tools for your IE.  This has become essential for me to troubleshoot and debug web pages.  I took a look at your page.  In the dev tools look for find in the menu and choose select element by click.  Do this for several img.  Look to the right of the dev screen and select layout.  I noticed the offset varied between different pictures.
See this other SO topic [How do I get rid of an element's offset using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817745/how-do-i-get-rid-of-an-elements-offset-using-css).  Your on the right track with the css reset i saw in your code.  Just keep going.  The article mentions positioning as a possible cause.

As Per Issue #2
I wish i had more time to dig into this.  I researched the error and found many hits most likely a syntax error.  See this SO topic [Possible cases for Javascript error: "Expected identifier, string or number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149762/possible-cases-for-javascript-error-expected-identifier-string-or-number)

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, this does help me at least see what the problem is! Unfortunately, when I change or call out a new offset for a quick fix in IE, it screws up the positioning of the other images and how the are viewed in the other browsers. Could this be somehow because of the js i am using in the document to display the image galleries?

Comment: All the JS should be doing is swapping the src of the img.  I will look into it more.  I think your best bet is to test the position and float of your img's.