# Strange input offset issue with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a strange offset problem with IE (IE9 in particular) that doesn't go away,
one `input` box has a higher offset (stands lower) than the other when there should be no reason to.

[Here is a zoomed-in version where you can see the offset](http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/6387/3yd.png).

I have removed all the other elements including CSS styles, and I still can't get rid of this offset issue.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="login" value="login" />
<input name="loginusername" style="height:16px;" type="text">
<input name="loginpassword" style="height:16px;" type="password">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is the first `input` and the box model from IE](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/2972/7r3v.png), which shows all the `padding`, `margin` and `offset` details.

[Here is the second `input` box model from IE](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/8115/fuy.png).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems weird, but you can try setting `vertical-align: top` in the CSS for the inputs. That fixes it in IE8, at least.

Comment: thank you very much, "vertical-align: top" fixed the strange issue, though I think it should have worked without it in the first place. also working in: http://jsfiddle.net/shahram/pgjAQ/

Comment: welcome to internet explorer, where many things should work but they just don't

Comment: Hello from the future! Where you just gave me the answer at the end of an  ENTIRE day trying to fix a similar issue. I'm almost crying.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: [How do I get rid of an element's offset using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817745/how-do-i-get-rid-of-an-elements-offset-using-css). The offset is a value calculated by the browser, depending on the CSS. It matters on the value of the position style in the CSS. Therefore, the problem can be fixed by adding position:absolute; to the inline CSS.

Here's your revised code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="login" value="login" />
<input name="loginusername" style="height:16px;" type="text">
<input name="loginpassword" style="height:16px; position:absolute;" type="password">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: thank you guys, "vertical-align: top" suggested by Perro also fixed my problem, I think that one should be better, though I can't point my finger at any advantages. this offset shouldn't exist in the first place in IE as it is with other browsers.

Comment: @shar Also, make sure to mark the one that helped you the most as the answer and close this thread!